# Backup and Restore Sitecollection: users on target machine not existing

Tags: user-profile, site-collection, backup, restore, user-accounts

I backed up a sitecollection from Server A and restored that sitecollection to server B using stsadm backup and stsadm restore.

Before the backup I removed the users from the sitecollection user groups because these users won't have a login on Server B. So they don't appear on Server B in the users and groups section of the restored sitecollection.

However, the users who added the content on Server A are shown in "Content and Structure" in the "Changed By" and "Contact" row.

But clicking on that user in "Content and Structure" returns a "User not found"-Exception.

That makes sense, but isn't very nice.

Is there a way around that? Maybe show the users in history but disable clicking on the user profile?